# Train speech recognition for specific words in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have just tried different API for speech recognition (google one, MS one and Houndify) but I am not satisfied beacause it takes too long to give the output (5-10"). So, since it has to understand only few of words (switch off, switch on...) I'd like to know whether there is a way to train the pc with those words in Python.
Which tools do I need? Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pocketsphinx and specify a grammar or keyword list.